# Problem With Echo Knowledge Base Wordpress Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I use echo KB WordPress plugin to show my website Faqs.
but the problem is I have 7 different categories and plugin supports only 6 categories for displaying items in tabs layout and when you add 7th category its face automatically changes to the dropdown menu, not tabs.
so I want to have 7 tabs without converting to the drop-down.
I reviewed all PHP and JS files in this plugin and I found this JS file that I think is related to my problem ( where //dropdown begins) :

```js
// Tabs Layout: switch to the top category user clicked on
 tabContainer.find( navTabsLi ).each(function(){

  $(this).on('click', function (){
   tabContainer.find( navTabsLi ).removeClass('active');

   $(this).addClass('active');

   tabContainer.find(tabPanel).removeClass('active');
   changePanels ( $(this).index() );
   updateTabURL( $(this).attr('id'), $(this).data('cat-name') );
  });
 });

 // Tabs Layout: MOBILE: switch to the top category user selected
 $( "#main-category-selection" ).change(function() {
   tabContainer.find(tabPanel).removeClass('active');
   // drop down
   $( "#main-category-selection option:selected" ).each(function() {
    var selected_index = $( this ).index();
    changePanels ( selected_index );
    updateTabURL( $(this).attr('id'), $(this).data('cat-name') );
   });
  });

 function update_query_string_parameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(re)) {
   return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  }
  else {
   return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
  }
 }
```

[image: 6 categories and tabs layout is OK]
[image: added 7th Category and it changes to drop-down menu]

Echo Knowledge Base Plugin Download Page:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/echo-knowledge-base/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong that it could be a javascript code that has limited the count of tabs layout.
there was a PHP file in path: echo-knowledge-base\includes\features\layouts 
to remove this limitation you need to change this line of code

```
if ( $nof_top_categories <= 6 )
```

I've changed number 6 to 7 and my problem has been solved.